# Jquery DatePicker shows up behind other regular page elements

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker, focus

I am having a trouble with a date picker implemented by someone else.  I tried to implement the code on my website but it's not working.  Below is the Javascript DatePicker

```
// init datepicker
function initDatepicker(){
    jQuery('.with-datepicker').each(function(){
        var hold = jQuery(this);
        var input = hold.find('input:text');
        var opener = hold.find('.btn');
        input.datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true
        })
        opener.bind('click', function(e){
            input.focus();
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    })
}
```

So my issue is 2 fold.
A) I don't understand what input.focus() is really doing other than calling focus on `jQuery(this).find('input:text').focus();`
B) The datepicker with the class of ".with-datepicker" shows up behind other elements on the page, and when I try to click on the datepicker it goes away and does not select a date.

A little more information to give you is I am using this with Contact Form 7 which has a text box you can click on to activate the date picker.  That part seems to work ok.  The datepicker literally shows up right below the input box that displays "pick a date".  The problem is the datepicker class is behind other elements such as radio buttons.

I also tried doing this after `input.focus();`

```
$(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
$(this).parent().css('z-index', 3000);
```

Below is a link to how it looks on the page:
[image: http://www.camdixon.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Capture.png]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your **DatePicker** has `position: absolute;`

And wrapper should have `position: relative;`,
other child elements of it should Not have `relative` positioning.

Your problem is in finding the correct parent, and giving correct `z-index` to the Active DatePicker.

Comment: What do you mean by select blocks?

Comment: I mean that Tags, which you have to click, for the DatePicker to be shown. Fore example `Event Date 1st Choice` button in here. 


**Each** pair of such button and Datepicker should have **one parent**. **OR** you can place the Datepicker(`position: absolute;`) inside the "button" block with `position: relative;` and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

I solve that just with css

```
.ui-datepicker { z-index: 10000 !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give `position:absolute` to the datepicker element and `position:relative` to the parent element of datepicker element

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't work for me.  $(this).parent().css('position', 'relative');
$(this).css('position', 'absolute');
$(this).css('z-index', 3000);

Comment: Apply this in style sheet.

Comment: Oh, you mean do this in CSS instead of jQuery

Comment: Yes add the positioning in CSS