# Move calendar in front of menu bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, calendar

Good morning, I've been racking my brain on this one for a bit. I have a calendar pop up that shows up when you click into a texbox. This calendar works fine, except for the fact that it shows up behind the menu bars.

[image]

I've been trying to get it to show on top by using z-index, but I've got no luck. Is there a way to make all javascript show up on top? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -0, maxDate: "2Y+1M+7D",
            changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths:2,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
            dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy",
            showAnim:"drop" });//fold, slide, blind, bounce, slideDown, show, fadeIn, clip.
  });
```

There's also a ton of CSS involved that I can't really post here. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033420/jquery-date-picker-z-index-issue, or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513291/jquery-datepicker-shows-up-behind-other-regular-page-elements

Comment: Thank you! That was it! I don't know why I didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CSS way:

`#datepicker{position:relative;z-index:100;}`

Or you can try jQuery way:

`$('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ndUN/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell where the problem lies from the code you shared, but I have had this happening to me before. The problem usually is in the HTML layout. Make sure the date picker is not inside another element that is stuck with a relative position. You may try to move it outside any parent elements.

*this wouldn't work*

`<body>
        <nav style="position:fixed;">
            <!-- insert menu here -->
        </nav>
        <div style="position:relative;">
            <div id="datepicker"></div>
        </div>
    </body>`

*but this will*

    `<body>
        <nav style="position:fixed;">
            <!-- insert menu here -->
        </nav>
        <div style="position:relative;">
        </div>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </body>`

Sorry if this doesn't help. I'm just going with a hunch based on what had happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

Ben Sewards gave me the solution with his link. I just needed to add some CSS to the actual texbox. Thank you everyone.